# Certificate/Keystore Configuration Issue - JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss, keystore, keytool, truststore

I've been trying to get this working for a while now and am just about at the end of my rope.  I'm trying to add the certificate that I obtained from a secure site to a local keystore and truststore, and then have a JBoss 7.1 configuration pick it up.  The documentation I have primarily been attempting to follow is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html.

Here is what I'm executing:

> 1. keytool -genkey -alias myalias.com -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keystore keystore.jks
> 2. keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias myalias.com -file downloaded-certificate.pem
> 3. keytool -export -alias myalias.com -file cacerts.cer -keystore keystore.jks

This is the relevant portion of my JBoss 7.1 standalone.xml file:

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
    <ssl name="ssl" password="changeit" key-alias="myalias.com" certificate-key-file="${JBOSS_HOME}/keystore.jks" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="true" ca-certificate-file="${JBOSS_HOME}/keystore.jks"/>
</connector>
```

And finally, this is the top of the stacktrace written in the logs when JBoss starts:

```
15:39:35,882 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error initializing endpoint: java.io.IOException: SSL configuration is invalid due to No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.checkConfig(JSSESocketFactory.java:788) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:493) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:168) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:977) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:190) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
etc...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide a keystore, you need to specify an alias such as the following in the ssl section

```
key-alias="myalias.com"
```

Also, I think the certificate-file is ca-certificate-file.

Comment: Ah, that bit about the alias definitely makes sense.  I'll also double-check the schema for the proper attribute for the certificate file.  Thanks!  I'll try these out in the morning and will update this post with the outcome.

Comment: I'm still having issues... when I specify an alias, the error thrown is "Alias name myalias.com does not identify a key entry."  This seems strange because if I export the contents of keystore.jks, the key entry name is present.  Updating the info above with the current configuration.

Comment: Strangely enough... despite the fact that the above error is being thrown when JBoss starts, the deployed application is now working properly.  Calling it good for now.

Answer (score 0):

Certificate/Keystore Configuration Issue - JBoss AS 7

Step 1: Add this line in standalone.xml file

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="8443"/>
            <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
                <ssl name="foo-ssl" key-alias="foo" password="name" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/test.keystore" protocol="TLSv1" certificate-file="../standalone/configuration/intermediate.cer"/>
            </connector>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="test.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

Step 2

Add this line in web.xml file

```
<security-constraint>
         <web-resource-collection>
             <web-resource-name>HTTPs test</web-resource-name>
             <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
         </web-resource-collection>
         <user-data-constraint>
             <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
         </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Comment: this web.xml file is where.?  in wep application for which we need https ?

Comment: add web.xml file inside WEB-INF